# WPF MVVM IsDirty implementation

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am stuck with a simple but tricky problem. I know a lot have probably solved this problem but I am not sure what the best solution is.

I have a WPF application with a WEB API backend. I deserialize the responses directly into my viewmodels. The problem with this is that because the deserialization calls the setter the IsDirty flag gets set to true. What is the simplest and smartest way to make sure after deserialising the object is not set to IsDirty?

Yes i could just set another property like IsMonitoring and check if this is true and only set the IsDirty flag then but the problem is that sometimes we have a object graph which makes it tricky.

Any ideas are welcomed

Thanks for the help

Comment: simply you might reset IsDirty at the end of deserialization.. eventually assign a state at the deserialization process within the viewmodels

Comment: that would work for a simple class with only strings and int etc. but what if the class is more complex with references to other classes?

Comment: if you have a property IsDirty for each class then you have to implement resetting for each class.. but you could create an abstract class "IsDirtable" for example :) and to inherit this behaviour for all classes that have to be submitted to IsDirty checking

Comment: Hmm okag i could put that on the 'EntityViewModelBase' and then make alles the ViewModels inheriting from that class implement the method to clean which calls all its childs too...

Comment: I would implement an event (OnDeserializationEnd) in the base class and then attach the event in calsses with the method. When you carry out a deserialization you may raise this event at the end and all classes reset IsDirty

Comment: One very simple option is to manually remember to set the IsDirty flag to true after the user changes a property. As long as you don't bind to your Model directly but use a ViewModel.